# How to look from a list into DataFrame with list cells

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I want to check the values from `x_list` in columns[a] lists cells and if found the `x_dic` filled with `c` values in dictionary, so as an example row 1 will return this dictionary :

```py
x_dic = {'1':, '2':[130], '3':[130], '4':, '5':[130]}
```

here is my code:

```py
    x_list = ['4', '2', '3', '5', '1']
    x_dic = {'1':, '2':, '3':, '4':, '5':}
    df =
               a        b    c
    0   [1, 3, 4, 2, 5] 10  120
    1   [2, 5, 3]       15  130
    2   [1, 2, 3, 4]    20  140
    3   [1, 2]          25  110

    df.a.astype(str)
    for g in df['a']:
        for i in x_list:
            if i in g:
                x_dic[i] += c
    x_dic
```

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: Can you include the full error?

Comment: try replace `df['a']` with `df['a'].tolist()`